# Finding time between two dates that excludes weekends and within a specific working time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate the time taken between two dates within specific working hours.

Example:
Requested Date - 2022-02-17 16:30:00
Completion Date - 2022-02-21 07:00:00
Work Time - 07:30:00 - 17:00:00

Below is the script I have currently to filter out the weekend.

I am struggling to calculate the work time.

```
SELECT PN,ReqDate,CompDate,
(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,ReqDate,CompDate) - DATEDIFF(WK,ReqDate,CompDate) * 2880) +
CASE
WHEN DATEDIFF(WK,ReqDate,CompDate) = 1 AND DATEDIFF(DW,ReqDate,CompDate) <= 5 THEN 0
WHEN DATEDIFF(WK,ReqDate,CompDate) = 0 THEN 0
ELSE 1440
END AS TIMEMINUTES
FROM EXAMPLETABLE
WHERE ReqDate >= '2022-01-01'
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (DATEDIFF is a product specific function.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management

Comment: You spell out `MINUTE` correctly, [why not spell out `WEEK` and `WEEKDAY`, too](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)?

Comment: Am new using this and looked like it was cutting off so i shortened some of it. I can edit if needed.

Comment: Why exclude weekends and not holidays? Why not exclude other non-work days? Use a calendar as a starting point. You will understand more clearly the issues you need to address once your start and end dates span more than one week. If you want to wave your hands and claim that will never happen, then explicitly state that in your question. And I suggest you include sample date ranges along with your calculations - esp. date ranges that include a common holiday.

Comment: I am excluding holidays using another table to filter. This example is showing specific dates (not holidays) and able to filter out the weekend. What I was asking is how to filter out the weekend and only grab the work time specified in the example.

Answer (score -1):

I would loop over dates to find total working hours. Here is the sample code:

```
declare @WtStart  varchar(9) = '07:30:00'
declare @WtEnd    varchar(9) = '17:00:00'
declare @ReqDate  datetime   = '2022-02-17 16:30:00'
declare @CompDate datetime   = '2022-02-21 07:00:00'
declare @TotMins int
select @TotMins = datediff(minute, @ReqDate, convert(varchar(8), @ReqDate, 112) + ' ' + @WtEnd)

declare @LoopDate datetime
select @LoopDate = dateadd(day, 1, convert(varchar(8), @ReqDate, 112))
while(1=1)
begin
    if convert(varchar(8), @LoopDate, 112) = convert(varchar(8), @CompDate, 112)
    begin
        if @CompDate > convert(varchar(8), @LoopDate, 112) + ' ' + @WtStart
        begin
            select @TotMins = @TotMins + datediff(minute, convert(varchar(8), @LoopDate, 112) + ' ' + @WtStart, @CompDate)
        end
        break
    end
    if datepart(weekday, @LoopDate) not in(7, 1)
       and not exists (select 1 from HolidayTable where d = @LoopDay
    begin
        select @TotMins = @TotMins + datediff(minute, '19700101 ' + @WtStart, '19700101 ' + @WtEnd)
    end
    select @LoopDate = dateadd(day, 1, @LoopDate)
end

select @TotMins / 60.0 "TotHours"
```